# Can you require certain behaviour whenever a shared pointer is created?

Tags: c++, graph, shared-ptr

Suppose I'm building a program that will hold a graph defined by Edge and Vertex objects, each with their own data and functionality. The edges and vertices are each stored in a vector of pointers, and since we want to do modern C++ these will be shared pointers, not naked pointers. Each edge is defined by two vertices and must include pointers to those vertices, and each vertex must also contain a list of all edges connected to it.

The complication is that I would like these relationships to be automatic and unavoidable: you cannot create an edge without associating it with two vertices *nor* without associating the two vertices to the new edge.

With a vector of naked pointers I feel like this is very easy:

```
#include <vector>
using std;

class Edge;
class Vertex {
public:
  Vertex=default;
  void addEdge(Edge* p_edge) { m_edges.push_back(p_edge); }
private:
  vector<Edge*> m_edges;
};

class Edge {
public:
  Edge(Vertex* p_vertex0, Vertex* p_vertex1):
     m_vertices{p_vertex0, p_vertex1}
{
  //Associate each vertex with the new edge everytime ctor is called
  p_vertex0->addEdge(this);
  p_vertex1->addEdge(this);
}
private:
  std::pair<Vertex*,Vertex*> m_vertices;
};


int main() {
vector<Vertex*> vertexList;

//...Initialize list of vertices...

//Add an edge
int index0 = 0, index1 = 1; //arbitrary
vector<Edge*> edgeList;
edgeList.push_back(new Edge(vertexList[index0], vertexList[index1]));

}
```

But when using shared pointers, what I want the vertices to have is the shared pointer for the edge, not the naked pointer, but when the ctor for the Edge is called the shared pointer doesn't exist yet, and I'm left doing this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std;

class Edge;
class Vertex {
public:
  Vertex=default;
  void addEdge(shared_ptr<Edge> p_edge) { m_edges.push_back(p_edge); }
private:
  vector<shared_ptr<Edge>> m_edges;
};

class Edge {
public:
  Edge(shared_ptr<Vertex> p_vertex0, shared_ptr<Vertex> p_vertex1):
     m_vertices{p_vertex0, p_vertex1}
{
//Cannot add edge to vertices here because we don't have the shared_ptr yet
}
private:
  pair<shared_ptr<Vertex>,shared_ptr<Vertex>> m_vertices;
};

int main() {
vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>> vertexList;

//...Initialize list of vertices...

//Add an edge
vector<shared_ptr<Edge>> edgeList;
int index0 = 0, index1 = 1; //arbitrary
edgeList.push_back(make_shared<Edge>(vertexList[index0], vertexList[index1]));

//Manually associate each vertex with new edge
auto vertex0 = vertexList[index0];
(*vertex0)->addEdge(edgeList.back());
auto vertex1 = vertexList[index1];
(*vertex1)->addEdge(edgeList.back());

}
```

This "works", but it is very unsecure in that it's easy to end up with onesided or mismatched relationships if you don't remember to make those calls every time you create a new edge.

So is there some way to ensure that everytime a shared_ptr is created, anywhere, anytime, that the associated vertices are given the shared_ptr corresponding to the new edge?

Comment: We do modern c++, hence shared pointers: No! Modern c++ means using the appropriate pointer type. And shared pointer when there's really just one graph owning all the vertices and edges makes no sense.

Comment: What you need is `std::reference_wrapper` instead of shared pointers, your design has the cyclic dependency problem where `Edge` has a shared_ptr to `Vertex`, and that `Vertex` also has a shared_ptr to that `Edge`, so both objects will never get destroyed and will cause a memory leak.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  This is a pretty significant simplification of the actual code.  My best understanding is that a shared_ptr will be useful here as the actual "vertex" and "edge" lists will need to be owned by a large number of a different objects.  Assuming that I am stuck using a shared_ptr, is there a way to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: @thedemons  that's a good point, I hadn't thought of the circular dependency issue.  I'll give reference_wrapper a try.  As for why we can't add the edge because we don't have it yet?  Because we don't have it yet.  How would I access the shared pointer corresponding to the new edge within the ctor of the new edge (in order to pass it to the vertices)?

Comment: @lemmox you really need to be sure that in your system, you don't end up with a cycle, where you have an object (e.g. an edge) that holds a shared pointer to another over (e.g. a vertex) which [...] holds shared pointer to the first object. Because then, that object can never get destructed, because that would require the shared pointer it holds to be destructed, and that in the end would require it to be destructed before it can be destructed

Comment: @MarcusMüller am I correct then that this may be a use-case for weak pointers (to avoid this circular dependency)?

Comment: It could be, but to be honest - this is a graph. That means you know the dependencies. In fact, you keep them in vectors! You should implement a destructor that goes through the adjacent objects, and removes the reference to the own object in their vectors. If the list of adjacent objects is empty, remove that neighbor from the object registry. That way, you would use raw pointers to the neighbors in your vertices and edges, because the lifetime of each object is deterministically defined by the graph structure. No need to replicate it by a reference counting shared or weak pointer!

Comment: In general use shared pointers with care. Because the risk is indeed there you will end up with cyclic references. The only place I really use them is in concurrency where the object is passed between objects with different life cycles. For graphs I would use `std::vector<Node>` and two maps (incoming and outgoing edges) std::map<Node,Edge>` to manage the life cycles of the nodes and edges. Edges can contain data and references (or non owning pointers) to nodes. Summary, manage your lifecycle seperately

Comment: Have a class `Graph` that owns all the vertices and edges (e.g. via `std::unique_ptr`). Then have vertices and edges cross-reference each other using plain non-owning pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual overhead notwithstanding, your Edges and Vertices have shared_ptr's into each other. That means they will very likely leak unless you take manual precaution.

This indicates that shared_ptr might not be the most suitable tool here.
Also, it requires each vertex and edge to be allocated separately, which is not great.

I would recommend a more lightweight design:

```
std::vector<std::optional<Vertex>> vertices;
std::vector<std::optional<Edge>> edges;
std::vector<std::size_t> freeListV; // unused vertex-slots
std::vector<std::size_t> freeListE; // unused edge-slots

struct Vertex {
  std::vector<std::size_t> neighbours; // index into edges vector
};
struct Edge {
  std::array<std::size_t, 2> vertices; // indices into vertices vector
  WeightType w;
};

void addEdge(std::size_t i0, std::size_t i1, WeightType w) {
  // make sure no such edge exists
  if (freeListE.empty()) {
    freeListE.push_back(edges.size());
    edges.push_back(std::nullopt);
  }
  auto const eid = freeListE.back();
  freeListE.pop_back();
  auto& edge = edges[eid];
  edge = Edge{std::array{i0,i1}, std::move(w)};
  vertices[i0].push_back(eid);
  vertices[i1].push_back(eid);
}
```

You can delete an edge/vertex by assigning std::nullopt to its slot in the corresponding vector. Make sure no vertex/edge points to it before nulling it. If you don't need to ever delete an edge/vertex, you can completely do without the freeLists.

The advantage: much less indirection, cache-locality, no danger of leaks.